# Hide bar when changing the meter

Tags: musixtex

Using `musitex`, I'm trying to do a excerpt of music with two staffs, and on the upper one I want to remove the vertical bars. Also, I want to change the meter at each bars.

Without changing the meter, I'm able to remove the bars from the upper staffs with `\sepbarrules\hidebarrule{2}`, but when I add the meter change they reappear!

Below a MWE with the output

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{musixtex}

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
      \instrumentnumber{2} % 2 instruments
      \nobarnumbers
      \generalmeter{}
      \setclefsymbol{1}\empty % Remove the clefs from the lower staff
      \setclefsymbol{2}\empty % Remove the clefs from the upper staff
      \setlines{1}{0}         % Remove the staff lines from the lower staff
      \setlines{2}{0}         % Remove the staff lines from the upper staff
      \interinstrument=-6\internote
      \nostartrule            % Remove the starting bar, does not work with '\changecontext'
      \sepbarrules\hidebarrule{2} % Does not work with '\changecontext'
      \startextract
        \setmeter2{}
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}
        \hidebarrule{2}             % Does not work with '\changecontext'
        \changecontext
        \sepbarrules\hidebarrule{2} % Does not work with '\changecontext'
        \notes\ql{l} \ql{l}&\hl{l}\en
        \setmeter2{}
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{3}{4}}}
        \changecontext%
        \notes\ql{l} \ql{l} \ql{l}&\hlp{l}\en
        \setmeter2{}
        \setmeter1{\meterC}
        \changecontext
        \notes\ql{l} \ql{l} \ql{l} \ql{l}&\wh{l}\en
      \endextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

[image: Staffs with bars]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Top vertical bars can be suppressed by redefining `\changecontext`.

[image: a]

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{musixtex}

%**************************************** added <<<<<<
\makeatletter
\def\changecontext{\n@wbar\updat@context}
\makeatother
%***************************************

\begin{document}
    \begin{music}
        \instrumentnumber{2} % 2 instruments
        \nobarnumbers
        \generalmeter{}
        \setclefsymbol{1}\empty % Remove the clefs from the lower staff
        \setclefsymbol{2}\empty % Remove the clefs from the upper staff
        \setlines{1}{0}         % Remove the staff lines from the lower staff
        \setlines{2}{0}         % Remove the staff lines from the upper staff
        \interinstrument=-6\internote
        \nostartrule            % Remove the starting bar, now works with '\changecontext'
        \sepbarrules\hidebarrule{2} % Now works with '\changecontext'
        \startextract
        \setmeter2{}
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{2}{4}}}
        \hidebarrule{2}             % Now works with '\changecontext'
        \changecontext
        \hidebarrule{2}             %Now works with '\changecontext'
        \notes\ql{l} \ql{l}&\hl{l}\en
        \setmeter2{}
        \setmeter1{{\meterfrac{3}{4}}}
        \changecontext%
        \notes\ql{l} \ql{l} \ql{l}&\hlp{l}\en
        \setmeter2{}
        \setmeter1{\meterC}
        \changecontext
        \notes\ql{l} \ql{l} \ql{l} \ql{l}&\wh{l}\en
        \endextract
    \end{music}
\end{document}
```

To avoid top vertical bars when using `\Changecontext` or similars , you can use a more drastic approach using instead

```
\renewcommand{\showallbarrules}{}
```